# I am trying to use the Wolfram Alpha API for an app in Java, but having problems with the Async class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, http-get, wolframalpha

I have all the necessary imports. If anyone could throw some light on perhaps why my InputStream is not being read that would be greatly appreciated. I believe it is this as my log returns a problem with the async class, but further in from that it seems to be (I could be wrong though) that the input stream is not being read as the given url. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[] currency;
EditText amount1;
TextView answer;
Spinner spin1;
Spinner spin2;

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException
{
    InputStream in = null;

    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if(!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP Connection");
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("Wolf Post", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw new IOException("Error Connecting");
    }
    return in;
}

//method to send information and pull back xml format response
private String wolframAnswer(int currencyVal, String firstSelect, String secondSelect)
{
    //variables are assigned based of user select
    int pos1 = spin1.getSelectedItemPosition();
    firstSelect = currency[pos1];

    int pos2 = spin2.getSelectedItemPosition();
    secondSelect = currency[pos2];

    amount1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAmount1);
    answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    InputStream in = null;

    String strWolfReturn = "";

    try
    {
        in = OpenHttpConnection("http://www.wolframalpha.com/v2/input="+currencyVal+firstSelect+"-"+secondSelect+"&appid=J6HA6V-YHRLHJ8A8Q");
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db;

        try
        {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(in);
        }
        catch(ParserConfigurationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        //retrieve the wolfram assumptions
        NodeList assumpElements = doc.getElementsByTagName("assumptions");

        //move through assumptions to correct one
        for (int i = 0; i < assumpElements.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node itemNode = assumpElements.item(i);

            if(itemNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                //convert assumption to element
                Element assumpElly = (Element) itemNode;

                //get all the <query> elements under the <assumption> element
                NodeList wolframReturnVal = (assumpElly).getElementsByTagName("query");

                strWolfReturn = "";

                //iterate through each <query> element
                for(int j = 0; j < wolframReturnVal.getLength(); j++)
                {
                    //convert query node into an element
                    Element wolframElementVal = (Element)wolframReturnVal.item(j);

                    //get all child nodes under query element
                    NodeList textNodes = ((Node)wolframElementVal).getChildNodes();

                    strWolfReturn += ((Node)textNodes.item(0)).getNodeValue() + ". \n";
                }
            }

        }



    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        Log.d("Network activity", io.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return strWolfReturn;
}
//using async class to run a task similtaneously with the app without crashing it
private class AccessWebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        return wolframAnswer(100, "ZAR", "DOL");
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //spinner implementation from here down
    currency = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currencies);

    spin1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinCurr1);
    spin2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinCurr2);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currency);

    spin1.setAdapter(adapter);
    spin2.setAdapter(adapter);

    //using httpget to send request to server.
    amount1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAmount1);
    answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    Button convert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);

    convert.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //apiSend();
            new AccessWebServiceTask().execute();
        }

    });


}

/*public void apiSend()
{
    int pos1 = spin1.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String firstSelect = currency[pos1];

    int pos2 = spin2.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String secondSelect = currency[pos2];

    amount1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAmount1);
    answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Converting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try
    {
        //encoding of url data
        String currencyVal = URLEncoder.encode(amount1.getText().toString(),"UTF-8");

        //object for sending request to server
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

         String url = "http://www.wolframalpha.com/v2/input="+currencyVal+firstSelect+"-"+secondSelect+"&appid=J6HA6V-YHRLHJ8A8Q";

         try
         {

             String serverString = "";

             HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

             ResponseHandler<String> response = new BasicResponseHandler();

             serverString = client.execute(getRequest, response);
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "work 1work 1work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             answer.setText(serverString);
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             answer.setText("Fail 1");
         }
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
    {
        answer.setText("Fail 2");
    }

}*/

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You're more likely to get a reply if you only post the relevant section of code, rather than the entire file.

Comment: Changed the InputStream to a global varibale. Saw that I set it to null twice. Even so the app still bombs out on the async. It says:"FATAL EXCEPTION on AsyncTask #1"

Comment: Thanks Carl Anderson, this is my first time using stack overflow, will do so in the future.

Comment: Can you explain what error you're getting, or what line is being problematic?

Comment: From the onCreate downwards is probably irrelevant. The errors occur once I run so I am not sure about the line. As I see it it begins with: Illegal Argument Exception - InputStream cannot be null. then there is a runtime exception - an error occurred while executing doInBackground().

Comment: The logcat, where the error is reported, should list a line number. Stack Overflow doesn't show line numbers on posted code, but you can edit your code and leave some sort of addition like this: // <-- crash happens on this line

Comment: [Here is a screenshot of my logcat](http://imgur.com/bryma41). There are no line numbers. Apologies if I'm not getting something or missing something, only been working on Java and Android for a couple of months.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Logcat can be confusing, but it is actually telling you a line number:
"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.assignment1question2.MainActivity.wolframAnswer ( *MainActivity.java:128* )

Comment: So you can see from that line that the NullPointerException is on line 128.

Comment: Ok, so then it derives around the doc.getDocumentElement().normalize(); which is reading the xml data, if i am not mistaken. Would it then perhaps, not be returning any xml, so that there is nothing to be normalised, or the xml data that is being returned is not in the correct format, or lastly the data that is being sent does not make sense to the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're not getting a good connection.

```
if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
{
    in = httpConn.getInputStream();
}
```

At this point in the code you're setting the input stream, but if the result is not HTTP_OK, you're going to return `null`, and you're not handling that possibility correctly, neither in `OpenHttpConnection()` nor in `wolframAnswer()` where you call it. It seems something in your connection setup code is not correctly connecting, and thus your input stream is `null` and crashing when you try to parse it with the DocumentBuilder.

Comment: You are correct that I am not getting a good connection. But this derives from the    in = OpenHttpConnection("http://www.wolframalpha.com/v2/input="+currencyVal+firstSelect+"-"+secondSelect+"&appid=J6HA6V-YHRLHJ8A8Q");    section of the code. For some reason or another nothing is being passed to the OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) even though I am sending it arguments.

Comment: Do you know how to do logging with Logcat? http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html
You should add a bunch of logging statements to try to get to the bottom of what's going wrong.

Comment: You sir, are correct. I've isolated it to the point to just before your answer above. The response code is 404, which I am guessing is a usual 404 error, whilst the HTTP_OK code is 200. The 404 would mean that it is not getting the necessary response from the server. Which would probably mean that there is an error in the url...

Comment: Thank you for talking me through it, isolated it now to the url which i was sending as www.wolframalpha.com - when it should have been **api**.wolframalpha.com. It still isn't 100% but that is a major step forward, thank you!

Comment: Thanks, if you would be so kind as to mark my answer as the "accepted" answer (click the checkmark), I'd appreciate it.